# How to center a gwt application in the middle of the page

Tags: css, gwt

I am trying to center a gwt application in the middle of the page,I have tried the following.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
            RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

            Image image = new Image("images/board.png");


            FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();

            fp.add(image);
            fp.setStyleName("center");
            rootPanel.add(fp);

        }
```

I have a .center in my stylesheet within the gwt application that has the following.

```
.center{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 480px;
}
```

But this seems not to work.

Comment: Just to be sure. `container` is an id and `center` a class, which means it should be `.center` in the stylesheet....

Comment: Yes in the gwt stylesheet I have .center.Forget about container it is not being used anymore.I should update my code above which I will do now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably try;

HTML;

```
<head>
      <style type="text/css">
    div#container
{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width:480px;
}
        </style>

<script language="javascript" src="com.mycompany.project.TEST/com.mycompany.project.TEST.nocache.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container" align="center">


</div>
</body>
```

onmoduleLoad;

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("container");

        Image image = new Image("images/board.png");


        FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();

        fp.add(image);
        fp.setStyleName("center");
        rootPanel.add(fp);

    }
```

Comment: With this method, you put your application's main part to center. And other widgets replaced, comes to the center without giving style.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your css file

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.center{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 480px;
    text-align:left;
}